# How can i get window property from element

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<h1 id="a">Site 3</h1>

<script>

var arr = []

for(var i in window)
{
    arr.push(i) 
}
console.log("a" in window)// true
console.log(arr)// dont have property a why?!
</script>

</body>
```

But when I run console.log(arr) I don't have a in the array, why?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: exactly i want to get a and push it in arr

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: look at my code and if you know answer me why arr dont have element "a"

Comment: Why should your array have an "a" element?

Comment: This would be browser specific, the specs just say that *"the global object may have additional host defined properties..."*, and named elements being part of the global object is up to the vendor, and was introduced by Microsoft many years ago, is not standardized, and can be implemented differently

Comment: @adeneo: No, it's in the spec now: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Because when you put an `id` on an element, the browser creates an automatic global for it, and because until ES2015 all globals had to be properties of the global object (which `window` references on browsers), you end up with `a` on `window` being a reference to the `div` with that ID.

Comment: This was a very interesting question!

Comment: I didn't see the id=a. My bad. Turns out to just be an issue of an own property or not.

Comment: @charlietfl: Um, fairly sure it is. Example?

Comment: Yeah! javascript is so crazy ;d

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - oh, that's right, I always forget that HTML5 standardized that shit, it even says so in the old [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) about this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I retract ... didn't used to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [things accessible on `window`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) are not necessarily "own" properties of `window` and (this is the significant bit) are not necessary *enumerable*. `for-in` only visits enumerable properties (both "own" and inherited).

On Chrome, for instance, the automatic `a` global is a property of the prototype of the prototype of `window`, and it's marked as non-enumerable:

```js
var o = window;
var where = "window"
while (o && !Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "a")) {
  where = "prototype of " + where;
  o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
}

console.log(where);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "a"));
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Looks like it's in the same place on Firefox.

The exact semantics of how named access is achieved isn't dictated, so long as `in` works and `window.a` works.

Comment: ok, so why "a" is in prototype of prototype window rather than window?

Comment: @MankamentGra: According to the above it's on the *prototype* of the prototype of `window`. I don't know, at that point we're into implementation details, but `window` is **very** complicated, taking things from lots of different places, incorporating the [`WindowProxy` object](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-windowproxy-object), etc. I'm not surprised to find three layers to it.